# Cygwin: CD to Windows paths easily

Tags: zsh, cygwin

In Windows paths are (unreasonably) long, so it is common to drag and drop from some links to the terminal or copy and paste paths from file managers. It is possible to put in the shell init file a function like

```
cdw() { cd "`cygpath -u $1`"  }
```

Now we have a Windows version of `cd`. Assuming that "C:\Program Files" is in your clip,  you can type:

`cdw` "<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>"

and CD there. I agree with you, quoting is boring:  `cdw` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (no double quotes) would be the killer `cd`.
This is easy in Bash exploiting the `history` command,  as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825060/1851270). But I use `zsh`, where issuing  `history` does not return the very last command (i.e. `history` itself). By trial and errors I came up with this function:

```
cdw(){
  print -s 
  set $(fc -l -1 | tail -2 | head  -1)
  shift 2
  p=`cygpath -u "$*"`
  cd "$p"
}
```

It works but seems too convoluted. I wonder if you can find a solution more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That history hack is a really strange way to solve this problem, and it's pretty fragile. It won't work with some characters that are valid in Windows file names such as parentheses.

There's a much easier way to use to a pasted Windows path. Instead of pasting it into the line editor, call the `getclip` utility (which is [in `cygutils-extra` in recent versions of Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-06/msg00501.html)).

```
cdw () {
  cd -- "$(getclip)"
}
cd -- "`getclip`"/../foo
```

You can get away without the double quotes if the dir path contains no characters of `$IFS` (space, tab, newline and NUL by default).

If you want to be able to edit the path, bind a key to [`expand-or-complete-prefix`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-expand_002dor_002dcomplete_002dprefix), e.g. type `` "`getclip`" `` and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
bindkey '\e\t' expand-or-complete-prefix
```

Another approach is to bind a key to insert the quoted content of the clipboard.

```
insert-quoted-clipboard-content () {
  LBUFFER+=${(q)$(getclip)}
}
zle -N insert-quoted-clipboard-content
bindkey '^X^V' insert-quoted-clipboard-content
```

Comment: @Nathan It's a zsh builtin command.

Comment: I could not find bindkey in Cygwin.  I found bind instead.

Comment: @Nathan Bash has a builtin called `bind`. Zsh has a builtin with a similar purpose called `bindkey`. It's a difference between bash and zsh. It has nothing to do with Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

[Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles-so-stop-being-evil) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175205/56853) is for Zsh since the question is about Zsh.  Google dropped me on this page, but I use Bash.  The following works on Bash when added to `.bashrc`.

```
# Convert Windows paths to Cygwin paths and add " if necessary.  Then paste to the command buffer.
paste()
{
   local prefix=${READLINE_LINE:0:${READLINE_POINT}}
   local suffix=${READLINE_LINE:${READLINE_POINT}}
   local text=$(getclip)

   # Does the clipboard contents look like a Windows path (e.g., C:\Program Files)?
   if [[ ${text} =~ [A-Z]:\\.* ]]; then
      text=$(cygpath --mixed "${text}")

      # Add quotes if there are any spaces in the path
      if [[ ${text} == *" "* ]]; then
         text='"'${text}'"'
      fi
   fi

   # Insert the clipboard contents at the current cursor position
   READLINE_LINE=${prefix}${text}${suffix}

   # Move the cursor to the end of the inserted text
   ((READLINE_POINT += ${#text}))
}

# Remove Ctrl+V binding
stty lnext undef

# Change Control+v to execute paste()
bind -x '"\C-v":"paste"'
```

Comment: With your approach and without it, my paths are pasted using `/mnt` instead of using `/cygdrive` and I have to type it every time. Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: @Metafaniel I suggest adding some printfs to debug what is happening at the various steps.  This will probably reveal where `/mnt`.

Comment: A little bit later, I found an answer. I needed to add `-cur_console:pm:/cygdrive` to the command that launches the CygWin terminal using ConEmu under its task configuration. Thank you for the follow-up! Here's the URL where I found the answer: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/2082

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the question but, worst case scenario, I figure this could help someone else. There is no need<sup>1</sup> to create a function like `cdw` to `cd` to Windows paths. [Cygwin's `cd` already accepts them, so long as you wrap them in quotes.](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-win32)

e.g., `cd 'C:\Program Files'` will *C*hange your *D*irectory to `/cygdrive/c/Program Files`.

---

<sup>1</sup>: I'm intentionally using the word "need." There still may be a legitimate reasonable *desire* to create `cdw`.

Comment: Note that `cd` is a builtin of each shell, there's no such thing as a `cygwin cd`. Here the point is that pathname resolution in POSIX system calls emulated by cygwin including `chdir()` support both Unix-style and Windows style paths. See https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the information! For someone as inexperienced as me, I kept the wording the same because I think it might be easier for the typical cygwin user to understand. Obviously, I'm coming from a place of ignorance, so if you disagree, don't hesitate to edit my answer! :)